# Arquillian.arquillianBeforeTest Could not inject members

Tags: testng, jboss-arquillian

A TestNG Arquillian based unit test works fine on my Eclipse environnement but failed on the CI platform.

I get an incomplete log message :

```
Tests run: 151, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 82, Time elapsed: 2.921 sec <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
(com.timm.cdi.vaadin.i18n.LocalTimeProcessorTest)  Time elapsed: 0.454 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not inject members
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
...
Run 1: LocalTimeProcessorTest>Arquillian.arquillianBeforeTest:136 » Runtime Could not...
```

The project is using **arquillian-weld-se-embedded-1.1**.

How can I get more information on the defect ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you have in the testng report?

Comment: TestNG report return :,
inline 'Error Message
    
    Could not inject members
    
    Stacktrace
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not inject members
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException'

Comment: It was a problem with session management thread. I solve it by setting surefire maven plugin reuseForks configuration to false.